# Lookup element by id within a DIV not injected in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml

I have a DOM element in memory that is yet to be injected in the page DOM.
I want to lookup an element by id inside this DOM element but document.getElementById wont work as the element is not yet in the page DOM.

Any ideas on how to do this?

P.S.

- I know one approach is to use
  element.querySelector() but since IE7
  doesnt support it, I can't.
- Not using    Jquery

Comment: Was the DOM element created from the script? Or pulled from an external source? Did you already try searching the variable that contains the DOM element, like if the var is set to `myDOM` did you try `myDOM.getElementById("someID")`?

Comment: Do you basically want to know how to traverse XML from within a js variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It differs on if the browser is IE or non-IE. In either case you should use `XPath`. For Firefox and other compliant browsers, you would use `evaluate` and the Xpath query, with IE, you use `selectNodes`. So here they are side by side:

```
//Say you want an element with an id of "foo":
  var xpathQ = "//[@id='foo']";  // This is your query

  var myXML = someXMLsource;   // Get your XML  however you are getting it

 //Assuming non-IE

 var fooNode = myXML.evaluate(xpathQ, myXML, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

//Assuming IE

var fooNode = myXML.selectNodes(xpathQ);
```

And then do what you need to do with the element. I'm a bit embarrassed that IE actually makes this more clear cut, but every dog has it's day.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can write `$('#someId', divElement)`.